# Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization

Tags: angular, webpack

When I try to load the project, the following error is thrown

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization
```

.

Comment: Same issue did you find what is causing it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got that error after upgrading Angular, since I ended up with invalid tsconfig. Check your tsconfig.json and your tsconfig.app.json, check any paths set (in files/include/exclude) are actually matching your environment. Either update paths or move the config files.

```
"files": [
  "../src/main.ts", // added ../ to reflect current file structure
  "../src/polyfills.ts"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but required a different resolution. Turns out I was using an unsupported version of typescript (4.9.x) I had to downgrade it to the correct 4.8.x version to get the error to clear.

Comment: This seems to be my case as well (Angular v14). However, why does it happen? Is there any workaround except downgrading Typescript version?